# NavigationBar Colour Issue

Tags: xcode, swift, uicolor, navigationbar

I am having some issues matching colours.

I asked a question similar to this before but I am now having the same problem. I have set translucency to false and have converted this HEX colour to UIColor:

## 008A2E

Issue is that it is still not true to what it should be (digital colour meter gives different values). Is it because the colours are clipped and is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: If you see same colour (008A2E) is different for example on your monitor and on device, than it's ok. That's because of screen technology. So it doesn't matter if you use same colour, on different screens it will look different.

Comment: @gottlieb The colour on the storyboard is what it should be but in the simulator it doesn't look like it should. Have already tried resetting the simulator too.

Comment: lol, I just used your colour to set background colour of a view directly in storyboard (using "digital colour meter" I got RGB equivalent: 10, 122, 49). After a build & run, I've measured one more time, view's background colour and... RGB values were: 16,122,35. I think iOS and OS X are using different colour system, so it will be difficult for your to get right colour, unless someone had already same issue and somehow solved it.

Comment: ah ok that would make sense. Yeah I was sure I set it correctly in Xcode but clearly the colour profile is different or something.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension for this issue here, save it as a swift class and import your project.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        let red = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF)) / 255.0
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }

    convenience init(rgba: String) {
        var red:   CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue:  CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0

        if rgba.hasPrefix("#") {
            let index   = advance(rgba.startIndex, 1)
            let hex     = rgba.substringFromIndex(index)
            let scanner = NSScanner(string: hex)
            var hexValue: CUnsignedLongLong = 0
            if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexValue) {
                switch (count(hex)) {
                case 3:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF00) >> 8)       / 15.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F0) >> 4)       / 15.0
                    blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x00F)              / 15.0
                case 4:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xF000) >> 12)     / 15.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0F00) >> 8)      / 15.0
                    blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00F0) >> 4)      / 15.0
                    alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000F)             / 15.0
                case 6:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)   / 255.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8)    / 255.0
                    blue  = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x0000FF)           / 255.0
                case 8:
                    red   = CGFloat((hexValue & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
                    green = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
                    blue  = CGFloat((hexValue & 0x0000FF00) >> 8)  / 255.0
                    alpha = CGFloat(hexValue & 0x000000FF)         / 255.0
                default:
                    print("Invalid RGB string, number of characters after '#' should be either 3, 4, 6 or 8")
                }
            } else {
                println("Scan hex error")
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid RGB string, missing '#' as prefix")
        }
        self.init(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:alpha)
    }
}
```

> usage

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x008A2E, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: I did try to do that but it gave the same colour as before. Previously I was using a hex to UIColor converter as opposed to your method but they gave the same result.

Comment: hmm strange as for me it gave the same result as before.

Comment: i edited my answer for your case now, did you set it like that?

Comment: I did it with this code: UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x008A2E, alpha: 1.0)
It did do it as it produces a similar colour and if I remove that line it shows nothing but it isn't what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage HEX colour that I found is using directly in the **UIColor** constructor.

Thy this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0x00/255, green: 0x8A/255, blue: 0x2E/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

I hope help you.

Comment: I was using this code: UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x008A2E, alpha: 1.0)